# PHP code error with contact form

Tags: php, html

I am beginner in web developing, I am building a website which has contact form and when the details are entered the details has to be sent to my mail id. But I am not sure why the code is not working.

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["name"]==""||$_POST["email"]==""||$_POST["note"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['email'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$message = $_POST['note'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("[ email removed ]", $message, $headers);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
}
}
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hire-a-Tent</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="tel"><span>CALL US:</span> 9738479234 <br /><span style="padding-left:150px;">9731015469</span></div>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="sidebar">

            <div class="order-form">
                <div class="order-form-head">
                    <h1>Rent -a- Tent</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="taxi-line"></div>

                <!-- Contact Form -->

                        <form action="email_code.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
    <div class="inp"><input type="text" class="required" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name..." /></div>
    <div class="inp"><input type="text" class="required" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telephone..." /></div>
    <div class="inp"><input type="text" class="required" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email..." /></div>
    <div class="inp"><textarea class="required" name="note" id="note" placeholder="Message..."></textarea></div>
    <button type="submit"></button>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</form>

<?php include "email_code.php"?>

</div>  

            <div class="address-box">
                <img src="images/icon.png" class="icon" alt="" />
                <div class="text">
                <span>We are located at</span><br />
                85, 4th cross road,<br />
                GKW layout, vijayanagar<br />
                Bengaluru-40
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="character">
            <!-- <img src="images/transparent2.png" class="taxi-driver" alt="" /> -->

<marquee behavior="alternate">T2 Tent: Rs 100/day --- T3 Tent: Rs 200/day -- Sleeping Bag: Rs 50/day --</marquee>
</div>

            <div class="spacer"></div>

        <footer>
            <p><strong><br/><br/>Hire-a-tent</strong> &copy; All Rights Reserved. <!--Developed by the <a href="www.Hireatent.com">Frequency Themes --></a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does 'not working' mean?  Do you get any errors or warnings?  Have you checked your logs?

Comment: A definition of "not working" would be a great help to us and go a long way towards stopping your question from being down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here, so please go over my entire answer carefully.

*Firstly,* your entire code's execution is relying on the conditional statement it's set in:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){...}
```

where it is looking for and is relying on a named attribute of the same name, which would most likely be your submit button being:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

It needs to be named:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit"></button>
```

or use an input type with a name attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Then you have an undefined variable `$email2` which would most likely need to be `$email`, as per:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

Having used error reporting, would have both signaled an "Undefined index submit..." warning, as well as "Undefined variable email2...".

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Now, this line:

```
mail("[ email removed ]", $message, $headers);
```

It is missing the "subject" parameter, which is an important parameter when using `mail()`.

I.e.:

```
mail("[ email removed ]", $subject, $message, $headers);
```

therefore, you will need to add a variable for it.

I.e.:

```
$subject = "Form submission";
```

For more information on `mail()` and headers, visit:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

From the manual:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

---

To check if `mail()` has been in fact executed, change:

```
mail("[ email removed ]", $message, $headers);
```

to

```
if(mail("[ email removed ]", $message, $headers)){
   echo "Mail has been sent.";
    }

    else{
       echo "Error. Check your mail logs.";
    }
```

If/when you see "Mail has been sent.", then `mail()` has done its job.

If you don't receive mail, then check your Spam or contact your hosting company if you're on a hosted site.

If you're running this from your own computer, then make sure that PHP and mail are in fact installed, running and configured properly.

---

**Footnotes:**

You're using the following twice, which one of them can be safely removed:

```
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

---

**EDIT:**

To add other form variables to the message, first declare the POST variables:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
```

Then change `$message = $_POST['note'];` to `$comment = $_POST['note'];`

and then do:

```
$message = "$name\n$email\n$tel\n$comment";
```

The `\n` adds line breaks.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. Another thing, how can I add name, email, tel and message in the message variable. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @suhasks You're welcome. Reload my answer and look near the bottom under **EDIT:**

Comment: Hi Fred, I am getting an error when I add ($message = $name\n$email\n$tel\$comment;) for the \n I guess. Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Change that line to `$message = "$name\n$email\n$tel\n$comment";` @suhasks - I've made an edit to that effect in my answer.